# Upload File via MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to simply Upload file via MVC3 
this is my View :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pic";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Blog", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
}
```

and this is my actions :

```
public ActionResult FileUpload()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {
            if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
                                               Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
                uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

what is wrong with my code ??
I have this Error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

in this line

```
 if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add enctype attribute to the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Blog", FormMethod.Post,
                       new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` as parameter to your form and you're good to go. It will look like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Blog", FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

And don't check the file size for existence control. I suggest controlling if it's null in the controller side.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Blog", FormMethod.Post))
```

with

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Blog", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
```

to learn more about the meaning of enctype="multipart/form-data", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)